# How do I write multiple input to a csv file in two separate records?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to prompt a user for input of the definitions and answers of a spelling test, each of which can be kept as a string in a variable and written to a csv (txt) file. However, I am also trying to save both the definitions of words and their answers in separate records:

E.g.

```
    def_1,def_2,def_3,etc

    ans_1,ans_2,ans_3,etc
```

Please consider that I am new to coding and therefore have a very basic knowledge of Python.

```
def create_new_test():

    print "Create New Test"
# Prompts user to enter each definition and their answers.
definition = raw_input("Enter definition: ")
answer = raw_input("Enter word: ")
definition_2 = raw_input("Enter definition: ")
answer_2 = raw_input("Enter word: ")
definition_3 = raw_input("Enter definition: ")
answer_3 = raw_input("Enter word: ")
definition_4 = raw_input("Enter definition: ")
answer_4 = raw_input("Enter word: ")
definition_5 = raw_input("Enter definition: ")
answer_5 = raw_input("Enter word: ")
definition_6 = raw_input("Enter definition: ")
answer_6 = raw_input("Enter word: ")
definition_7 = raw_input("Enter definition: ")
answer_7 = raw_input("Enter word: ")
definition_8 = raw_input("Enter definition: ")
answer_8 = raw_input("Enter word: ")
definition_9 = raw_input("Enter definition: ")
answer_9 = raw_input("Enter word: ")
definition_10 = raw_input("Enter definition: ")
answer_10 = raw_input("Enter word: ")
## Writes input to the csv file. Defintions and answers are stored in two separate records.
with open('Test.txt','w',newline='') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp,delimeter=',')
    data    = [[definition,definition_2,definition_3,definition_4,definition_5,definition_6,definition_7,definition_8,definition_9,definition_10],
        [answer,answer_2,answer_3,answer_4,answer_5,answer_6,answer_7,answer_8,answer_9,answer_10]]
    a.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Could you be clearer about what the problem with what you have already written is? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? Your indentation is wrong - is this how your code really looks, or a copy-paste error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is crying out for a loop:

```
defs = []
answ = []
for _ in range(10):
    defs.append(raw_input("Enter definition: "))
    answ.append(raw_input("Enter word: "))
with open("test.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(",".join(defs))
    fp.write(",".join(answ))
```

Note that instead of e.g. `definition_4`, you would now use `defs[3]` (list indices are zero-based). You can also easily loop through your definitions:

```
for defn in defs:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('definition,answer\n')
    for index in range(0,10):
        definition = raw_input("Enter definition: ")
        answer = raw_input("Enter word: ")

        fp.write(definition + ',' + answer + '\n')
```

Is this what you're looking for?
This will produce a "csv" file looking like:

```
definition,answer
Has a long neck nad loves to eat trees,giraffe
Is blue and rain comes from it,sky
....
```

This would be a normal question+answer syntax in a CSV file, however for some reason you want to structure it so that they are horizontally aligned instead of vertically (not sure why..)

Was just about to write the answer @jonrsharpe gave, so if you really want a horizontal alignment instead of a tabular one, go with that.